# Table import from Excel formatting weird. Aligning different than other table

Tags: html, css

I am re-doing my high school track/cross country website. I have downloaded the files that were used in the original site and I am having issues with table formatting. Here is a pic:

[image]

You can see that the bottom table is spaced out much nicer than the top. I am sure there is a small line that I need to change but after a while of messing with stuff I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the HTML for the top (bad) table

```
<table frame="void" cellspacing="0" cols="5" rules="none" border="0">
<colgroup>
<col width="334" />
<col width="300" />
<col width="116" />
<col width="110" />
</colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" width="775" height="30" align="center" sdnum="1033;0;@"><strong>Shepherd High School Boys Outdoor Track Records</strong></td>
    </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" sdnum="1033;0;@">&nbsp;</td>
                <td height="22" align="left" sdnum="1033;0;@"><strong>Event</strong></td>
                <td align="left" sdnum="1033;0;@"><strong>Name</strong></td>
                <td align="center" sdnum="1033;0;@"><strong>Record</strong></td>
                <td align="center" sdnum="1033;0;@"><strong>Date</strong></td>
              </tr>
```

Here is the HTML for the good table

```
<table frame="void" cellspacing="0" cols="4" rules="none" border="0">
<colgroup>
<col width="334" />
<col width="300" />
<col width="116" />
<col width="110" />
</colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" width="775" height="30" align="center" sdnum="1033;0;@"><strong>Shepherd High School Boys Outdoor Track Records</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="22" align="left" sdnum="1033;0;@"><strong>Event</strong></td>
      <td align="left" sdnum="1033;0;@"><strong>Name</strong></td>
      <td align="center" sdnum="1033;0;@"><strong>Record</strong></td>
      <td align="center" sdnum="1033;0;@"><strong>Date</strong></td>
    </tr>
```

They are the same but they end up very different. Is there something in there that is messing with the layout? If you need anything else I will be glad to add it. Thank you.

Comment: In HTML5, it is considered standard **not** to close self-containing elements. It's `<col … >`, not `<col … />`. I know this wasn't part of your question, but I just figured I'd point it out.

Comment: Thanks. Always helpful to learn something new.